# How can I discard the time part of a DateTime in an OData query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, odata

We have database entities that have date properties that do not have a time compononent, e.g. `2017-01-01`.

Our third-party front-end components support automatically building OData queries based on user selections, so, if I want to find all entities with a start date after `1/1/2017`, the generated query string looks like this:

`http://localhost/odata/Entities?$top=20&$filter=StartDate ge 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z&$count=true`

Which is great, the time part is zero'd, so it should not matter... except... the SQL generated by the framework translates to:

`WHERE ([Extent1].[StartDate] >= convert(datetime2, '2017-01-01 02:00:00.0000000', 121))`

Notice that now it's added a time offset of two hours (based on our timezone), which means that the dates that we're saving (`2017-01-01`) are outside of the range of the filters. So, if we want to see records for `2017-01-01`, we need to set the filter to `2016-12-31`.

The code on the API controller looks like this:

`[EnableQuery(MaxNodeCount = DefaultMaxNodeCount)]
public IQueryable<Entity> Get()
{
    IQueryable<Entity> entities = Service.GetViews();
    return entities;
}`

The code then goes down the rabbit-hole into dependency injection and entity framework, etc, etc. If I put a breakpoint on that Get method, then the `entities` collection has all the data, without the OData magic applied to it. The controller is really the only point at which I can (maybe?) alter the incoming query to ensure that the time part is not being passed to SQL; and the only place where I control the code. But I have no idea how to do that.

I had a look at creating a custom attribute that inherits from FilterQueryValidator. I was hoping that would be the answer, but I could not see how to do it. I can see the name of the field that is being filtered, but not the actual filter value, and then it looks like it's read-only.

#### Update:

In testing with Postman, I found that if I send through a date, without a time, it works as expected;

`http://localhost/odata/Entities?$top=20&$filter=StartDate ge 2017-01-01&$count=true`

The SQL that is then generated:

`WHERE ([Extent1].[StartDate] >= convert(datetime2, ''2017-01-01 00:00:00.0000000'', 121))`

And that gives me the correct dataset.

Comment: Have you considered converting and storing your dates in UTC time, and just using local time for UI?

Comment: We were doing that, and it had it's own set of related problems. Ideally, we don't want the time component to be a factor here at all.

Comment: Ok, as long as you guys realize that the time also affects the date when the user is in another time zone and it's close to midnight.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what's causing the issue :(

Comment: The front end app has to know what time is it exactly. In the app you must to transform to the time of the server before send the query

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Odata date function in Odata query like this $filter=date(StartDate) ge 2017-01-01

```
http://localhost/odata/Entities?$top=20&$filter=date(StartDate) ge 2017-01-01&$count=true
```

For reference - [odata webapi datetime-support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/datetime-support)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to `DateTime` without time is the use of `Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date`, a date type without time component.
This is defined in the NuGet package `Microsoft.OData.Edm` (supports OData4 only).

Comment: Thanks. I looked into that a few days ago. It works well when I'm using Postman to submit data, but, when I use the 3rd party controls, they send through a DateTimeOffset and odata complains about a type mismatch between Edm.Date and DateTimeOffset, so it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: ok, with a third party system that is not compatible and you can't change, this is not a solution. But for those who are in control on both sides this might be a solution to consider.

Answer (score 0):

The [DateTime.Date Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) will return

> A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).

If you want get rid of timezone information you can use [DateTime.ToLocalTime Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns

> An object whose Kind property is Local, and whose value is the local time equivalent to the value of the current DateTime object

So basically you can put both together

```
var date = dateWithTimezone.ToLocalTime().Date
```

Comment: Hi @Ruapho, the question is not so much how to manipulate a DateTime object to extract only the date, but more how to manipulate the OData query to replace the DateTime component with a Date only component.